# Does routing table work like a per-IP-address firewall, while iptables work like a per-port firewall?

Tags: iptables, routing, firewall

I heard that [in a routing table, we can drop packets](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/58061/7894). Does that work like a per-IP-address firewall to prevent access to certain range of IP addresses from the local device?

In comparison, does `iptables` work as a per-port firewall to prevent access to certain port from the local device?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the “I heard that ...” part? Regarding `iptables`, have you considered the usefulness or otherwise of the `-s` and `-d` parameters?

Comment: How does a per-IP-address firewall work? How does a per-port firewall work? I do not believe it is possible to block local system connections to local ports using iptables. I can't think of a use case where it would be necessary to actively block/drop/deny access from a local process to a local port. It sounds like you are discussing using network level activities to try and restrict system process functions. That dog won't hunt.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, I have. See my update.

Comment: @Tim so why would `iptables` support specifying source and/or destination *addresses* if it’s a per-port firewall (whatever that means)?

Comment: Does a "per-port firewall" mean anything? What?